# Is there a way to compare 3D model files (STEP) using python?

Tags: python, image-processing, 3d, comparison, step

I work with a huge library of components (step files) that are currently used in various products. My goal is to identify parts with great similarity in order to unify them. At the moment I can think of two solutions:

1. Compare certain properties of the 3D data with a suitable python library. E.g. identify parts with similar volume and dimensions.
2. Convert step files to JPG and compare the images with one of the many image processing libraries.

Both have their pitfalls.

Is there a library that can handle step files or do you know a better way to solve the problem?

Comment: Your best bet is probably https://pypi.org/project/aocxchange/ or the unterlying http://www.pythonocc.org/

Comment: I don't know which formats you will get when you read a file, but probably one that you can compare rather well by iterating or checking keys.

Answer (score 0):

You are underestimating the complexity of this project. Once the STEP geometry is loaded, taking dimensions on it (apart from bounding box extents) can be really cumbersome. Very different parts can have the same volume and comparing bitmaps you completely ignore the hidden part of the geometry.

Comment: No, I don't. I aim to boil down the big mass of parts to a number of suggestions which can then be inspected by hand. 3 dimensions of the bounding box + volume is far from ideal but would instantly reduce the number of parts to be considered.

Comment: By comparing bitmaps I thought about creating 3 different ISO views per part and put them in one image.